# Wildcard SSL certificate for Tomcat and Apache which both on port 443

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have a wildcard ssl cert for domain "www.abc.com", which running on Apache and using port 80 for http & port 443 for https.

Now, I would like to add a new domain "www2.abc.com", which running on Tomcat and using port 8080 for http & port 443 for https.

Is there any conflicts if I use both on port 443?

Many thanks.

Comment: check `netstat` for occupied ports.

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically you can't have tomcat *and* apache listen on 443 at the same time. You could have Apache forward requests to tomcat and handle the encryption. Look up mod_jk, mod_proxy or mod_proxy_ajp for how to do this.

Once you do this, you can have multiple `<VirtualHost>` declarations for port 443 on Apache. If they all use the same wildcard certificate for `*.abc.com` this will work fine.

With this scenario, tomat probably won't be configured to do ssl at all. I'm recommending to use the protocol ajp (not http) for the forwarding part, as this will forward all necessary information about the nature of the connection to tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any conflicts if I use both on port 443?

yes, **you can't set two or more applications to listen on a same port** at the same time.